# SQL Server 2016 Removing words from a string using words from a table

Tags: sql-server, replace, split, sql-server-2016, cross-apply

I am trying to remove specific words/phrases from a list of strings. I have created a table of words to exclude. I need to remove any of these words that appear in the string. I would like to maintain a list of exclusion words/phrases which will grow over time as I discover more words/phrases I want to exclude.

As an example, I want to exclude the phase 'blown tyre', but if the word 'blown' appears without tyre, then I want to keep it.

Below I have some code which is close to working but doesn't fully exclude every word from ever line due to the cross apply. This also does not work with phases due to the spaces inbetween words. I am not sure if the cross apply and string_split is the correct approach to take.

**Please note:** I am using SQL Server 2016 with compatibility level 130

```
declare @String table (stringid int, string varchar(100))
declare @WordExclude table (wordexcludeid int, wordexclude varchar(50))

insert into @String values (1, 'The police were called'), (2, 'I noticed ice froze the door 
shut and wind blew the roof off'), (3, 'The car had a blown tyre due to the storm')
insert into @WordExclude values (1,'Police'), (2, 'Noticed'), (3, 'Shut'), (4, 'Blown tyre'), 
(5, 'Storm')

select 
    s.stringid 
    ,value stringwords
    ,replace(s.string, e.wordexclude, '')
from @String s
cross apply string_split(s.string, ' ')
join @WordExclude e
on string like '%'+e.wordexclude+'%'
```

Comment: You'll need to iterate here, likely with a rCTE. `REPLACE` doesn't accept a dataset of values to replace, just a scalar value.

Comment: You won't be able to use `string_split` breaking on spaces if you need to filter out phrases. As Larnu mentioned a recursive CTE is probably the best solution within T-SQL, but text manipulation tasks like this are often better managed with external scripting languages before bringing the data into SQL.

Comment: Given that `@String` contains apparently freeform text what do you expect to happen when `blown tyre` breaks across lines such as `blown<linebreak>tyre`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was trying to avoid nested `replace()` within my code. However I may do this first for phrases, as there aren't many nor can I see the list of phrases growing very quickly. Then I will removed single words using the table. I will look into a rCTE. Thanks for the advice.